# In Java, why is insertion or deletion in a Linked List a constant time operation? Isn't it misleading?

Tags: java, linked-list

> Insertion or deletion of an element at a specific point of a list, assuming that we have a pointer to the node already, is a constant-time operation.
>   - from [the Wikipedia Article on Linked list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LinkedList)

Linked list traversal in a single linked list always starts from the head. We have to keep going till we satisfy a given condition.

So that will make any operation worst case O(n) unless we are dealing with the head node.

We CANNOT DIRECTLY go to a given pointer in a linked list. So why is it said that it is a constant time operation?

EDIT:
Even if we have a pointer to the node, we have to start from the head only right? So how is it constant time operation

Comment: "Even if we have a pointer to the node, we have to start from the head only right?".  Wrong.  We have a pointer to the node.  We don't start from the head.  That's what "pointer to the node" means.

Comment: @S.Lott if we have [data1][ref1]--->[data2][ref2]--->[data3][ref3] then to delete node2 we need to set ref1 to ref3    If we directly know [ref2] what good is that information?

Comment: @redmave: the assumption that `LinkedList` implements a single linked list is wrong: it's a doubly-linked list.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer: In computer science, a linked list (or more clearly, "singly linked list") is a data structure that consists of a sequence of nodes each of which contains a reference (i.e., a link) to the next node in the sequence. from Wikipedia

Comment: @redmave: so? In Java a `LinkedList` implements a doubly-linked list. So not everything that applies to "a linked list" as you defined it "in computer science" necessarily applies to `LinkedList` in Java.

Comment: I quote from [the JavaDoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html): "All of the operations perform as could be expected for a doubly-linked list."

Comment: @redmave: You are right, for a single-linked list we need a pointer to the node before the insertion point. I changed the sentence in the Wikipedia article according to this. When iterating through a list, we can usually arrange this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of: the `LinkedList` implemented in the Sun JDK effectively has a link to the last element as well as to the first element (there's only a `head` entry, but `head.previous` points to the last element). This means that even in the worst case navigating through a list to an element indicated by an index should take n/2 operations. It's also a doubly linked list.

Apart from that: inserting into the beginning or end of a `LinkedList` is trivially O(1), because you don't need to traverse all elements.

Inserting/removing anywhere else depends on how exactly you do it! If you use an [`Iterator`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) (of a [`ListIterator`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html) for adding) then the operation can be O(1) as well, as the `Iterator` will already have a reference to relevant entry.

If, however, you are using [`add(int, E)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add%28int,java.lang.Object%29) or [`remove(int)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove%28int%29), then the `LinkedList` will have to *find* the relevant entry (O(n)) and *then* remove the element (O(1)), so the entire operation will be O(n).

Comment: Thanks! Clever way of linking tail to the head.

Answer (score 7):

You said it yourself: "assuming we have a pointer to the node already".  That avoids the traversal you identify as the cause of the linear time.

Admittedly, the Wikipedia text is a bit ambiguous, since there are two nodes involved: the one being inserted, and the one in the list where to insert it.

Answer (score 5):

" assuming that we have a pointer to the node already, is a constant-time operation"

You missed the first assumption, it seems.

Answer (score 5):

You are missing the point I think here. It is just the INSERTION and DELETION that have a constant time not the finding the point of insertion or deletion as well!
The time is constant because you simply need to set the references (links) to the previous and next item in the list -- whereas for instance with ArrayList, in the case of insertion you need to allocate memory for (at least) one more item and transfer the existing data into the newly allocated array (or with deletion you have to shift elements in the array around once you deleted the item).

Comment: Its single linked, you can't set the previous item's reference to the next item. So I agree with OP that deletion is O(n), although insertion is of course O(1). In fact, if you don't have a reference to the head for deletion, it would be Θ(n).

Comment: Also array list is generally O(1) amortized insertion, not quite sure about deletion though, probably O(n).

Comment: @mathepic - that is solved by keeping a pointer to the node before the node to be deleted as you walk the list.

Comment: @Stephen C we aren't guaranteed that though, we are only guaranteed a pointer to the node we want to delete. For example, if all the nodes are pointed to by some map (for whatever reason) we might not have the pointer the node.

Comment: @mathepic: I changed the sentence in the Wikipedia article to require a pointer to the node before it. When iterating through a list, we can usually arrange this.

Comment: @mathepic - if we are not guaranteed that, then the problem is in the details of how we implemented the link traversal.  The original wording of the Wikipedia article may leave something to be desired ... but it is just a problem of wording.  The point that (I assume) the author was *trying* to make is valid.