# Sorting using a custom API - removeAndAppend

Tags: performance, algorithm

We are given an API -

```
removeAndAppend(val)
//Removes val and appends it to the given collection
```

we need to sort the collection using this API..

I know that I can do this by -

```
for i <- N to 1
    extract max //in O(n) 
    removeAndAppend.. //Consider this O(1)
```

this is quadratic..

The question is can I do better than this..?

EDIT: We can do READ operations on collection like - compare(val1, val2)

Comment: What API is this? And what language? Or is this pseudocode?

Comment: I can imagine a linked list can allow u to removeAndAppen in constant time.. i dont think language/pseudo code matters here.. please correct me if i m wrong

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5732974/264775) about insert and remove in Java. Does it sound like what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**With no additional data structures / constant space restriction:**

The `O(n2)` algorithm you described is essentially [selection sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort).

If you have access to an iterator of some kind (if not, how else would you access elements in the collection?), I believe one can do better by using a custom [merge-sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) as follows:

- Compare element 1 and 2. `removeAndAppend` the smaller one, then `removeAndAppend` the remaining one. Do the same for element 3 and 4, 5 and 6, ... and element n-1 and n.

  Now you'll have sorted subcollections of 2 elements each.
- Merge indices (1,2) and (3,4). To do this, have 2 iterators starting from the beginning. Start by incrementing the one twice. Then proceed to do a merge-sort as usual using the `removeAndAppend` function. Do the same for (5,6) and (7,8), (9,10) and (11,12), ... and (n-3,n-2) and (n-1,n).

  Now you'll have sorted subcollections of 4 elements each.
- Merge size 4 collections similar to above, then 8, 16, 32, etc., until you reach the collection size.

The whole process will look something like this:

```
// setSize is how large sets we're currently merging
for setSize = 1; setSize <= n/2; setSize *= 2
  iterator left = begin
           right = begin
  for pos = 1 to n/(2*setSize)
    // here right and left are both at the beginning
    // even after the previous iteration of the loop,
    //   since we've removed and appended all other elements
    // so we only need to increase right by setSize
    right += setSize

    for i = 1 to 2*setSize
      if (left.value <= right.value)
        removeAndAppend(left)
      else
        removeAndAppend(right)
```

The above is just a basic draft, it might not be 100% correct and doesn't account for when the collection isn't a power of 2 (which will happen often). You need to be careful in this case otherwise you might wrap around, or not go far enough and end up with a partially sorted collection.

The complexity analysis should be almost identical to regular merge-sort and result in an `O(n log n)` running time.

**With additional data structures / no constant space restriction:**

Extract all the elements into another collection, sort this in `O(n log n)` (using a sorting algorithm of your choice) and iterate through the sorted set, calling `removeAndAppend` on the original collection for each.

If you're not allowed to extract elements, this method can still be used by having a collection of indices instead and, to do a compare, simply look up the applicable elements. However, for this to be efficient, you'll need constant time lookup by index.

Comment: I was looking for this - "If there is a constant space restriction (this seems like the most probable case), I don't think you can do better than quadratic."
I think the quoted statement is correct because I need to do some processing(some logic for ordering) before using removeAndAppend..  removeAndAppend on N elements is definitely linear time.. 

Can we prove that quadratic is the best we can get..? I am not good at this :(

Comment: I cannot do merge sort without O(n) space.. I was expecting something in place..or at the most constant space..
But I get the idea u r describing.. tnx

Comment: We're reusing the same space as the input, so it should classify as O(1) **extra** space (which is usually how we define space complexity).

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursion, and many collections, split the in-parameter collections on its first element: lesserequal, and greater, recurse on both and merge. Complexity of merge-sort, search internet.

Comment: I don't think you're allowed to remove an element from one collection and insert it into another.

Answer (score 0):

`RemoveAndAppend` append at the end of collection?

Well, if this method has `O(1)` seems like the crucial question is how to find current max in the unprocessed part of collection - once the max is remove and append to the end.

Look at [What is the best way to get the minimum or maximum value from an Array of numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424800/what-is-the-best-way-to-get-the-minimum-or-maximum-value-from-an-array-of-number)

Answer (score 0):

Read the entire collection, sort it in your application, then "removeAndAppend" the values in the right order (which is now known).